# When would I use "¿Qué te gustan?"

Tags: uso-de-palabras, vocabulario

I recently came across the following in my Spanish notes.

> ¿Qué te gusta(n)?  What do you like?

I understand the usage of *¿Qué te gusta?*, but when would I use *¿Qué te gustan?* A plural form of what do you like does not make sense to me. When would I use *¿Qué te gustan?* Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use that sentence just like that. "¿Qué te gustan?" sounds wrong. 
If you are going to use the plural you should add a subject in plural like i.e.

> ¿Qué carros te gustan? = Which cars do you like?

or you could also use `Cuáles`

> ¿Cuáles carros te gustan? = What cars do you like?

If you are having a conversation about cars you could just say `¿Cuáles te gustan?` and since you already know that you are talking about cars the other person will understand the question.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the response. I just got confused when seeing qué te gustan in my notes.